# Need help understanding a proof for this statement: show that the the closest integer to $a$ is $[a+\frac12]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For reference $[a]$ would be *the greatest integer not exceeding $a$* or the *greatest integer function*.

**Question**: Prove that $[a+\frac{1}{2}]$ is the closest integer to $a$

The very beginning of the proof confused me, it went like this: "It suffices to show that $|a - [a + \frac{1}{2}]|\leq \frac{1}{2}$"

This makes intuitive sense to me, however how do we *know* that the nearest integer *must be* at most $\frac{1}{2}$ away can we prove it or do we just take it as fact?

Here is an alternative proof I came up with however I run in into a similar issue, we have $a = [a] + \theta$ with $\theta$ in $[0,\frac{1}{2})$ or $[\frac{1}{2},1)$ , therefore $a$ is in $[[a],[a]+\frac{1}{2})$ or $[[a]+\frac{1}{2}, [a]+1)$. In case 1, $[a]$ is the closest integer to $a$ I don't know how to show that but I just assume so, In case 2, $[a]+1$ is the closest integer to $a$, again I dont know how to show that but I just assume it to be true.

It is trivial to show that $[a+\frac{1}{2}] = [a]$ in case 1, and similarly for case 2 we have $[a+\frac{1}{2}] = [a]+1$ and therefore the closest integer to $[a]$ is $[a+\frac{1}{2}]$ as claimed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just work it out directly:

For $x\in[0,1]$, the distance to the nearest integer is just $\min\left(|x-0|,|x-1|\right)$.

When $x\leq\frac{1}{2}$, then $|x-0|\leq\frac{1}{2}$. When $x\geq\frac{1}{2}$, then $|x-1|\leq\frac{1}{2}$. Therefore in all cases $\min\left(|x-0|,|x-1|\right)\leq\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: This is great thanks so much! Can we generalize this by adding an arbitrary integer $a$

Comment: @cheesewiz Yes, exactly so.

Answer (score 3):

**Theorem:** for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, the distance $d$ from $x$ to the nearest integer is at most $1/2$.

*Proof:* Suppose otherwise so that $d>1/2$. Therefore

1. Either $x-d$ or $x+d$ is an integer, and
2. There is no integer in $(x-d,x+d)$.

If $x-d$ is an integer, then so is $(x-d+1)$ and
$$(x-d+1) = x-d+2\frac{1}{2} <  x-d+2d = x+d$$
and so $(x-d+1)\in(x-d,x+d)$, contradicting $(2)$. The case where $x+d\in\mathbb{Z}$ breaks up similarly.

Comment: Worth mentioning I make the following two assumptions: if $p\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $(p\pm 1)\in \mathbb{Z}$, and if the distance between real numbers $x$ and $y$ is $d$, then either $x+d=y$ or $x-d=y$.

Comment: Thank you for the well-done anwser! how is x-d+1 an element of (x-d,x+d) though?

Comment: @cheesewiz yw (: I'll edit the answer to add a bit more detail.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks :))